# php echo css doesn't work

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having a weird problem with my css in combination with php.

This is my normal html + css (so no php) and that's the layout I want
[image: normal html]

The PHP code

**not relevant anymore, see below**

When I run the script in Chromium, I get his:
[image: php + chrome]

As you can see the background of the body (the salmon color) doesn't run through to the bottom and the textboxes and search button are pressed against the bottom.

However, when I run the script in Firefox:
[image: php + firefox]

The background of the body runs through to the bottom (I cut a piece of it because what's under it isn't important now) but the textboxes and search button are still pressed against the bottom.

I have tried escaping changing ' to " and escaping them but to no avail. I don't think there's something wrong with the css and html seeing as it works without the php but I find it odd that it gives different styling. When I browse to the regular html in Firefox and Chromium there's no difference

**Note: I have some experience in programming but am a noob when it comes to PHP or HTML/CSS so it could be that I'm just looking at this the wrong way**

---

New HTML code without echo but this gives just exactly the same:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- Set the viewport so this responsive site displays correctly on mobile devices -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ComicDB</title>
    <!-- Include bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Site header and navigation -->
    <header class="top" role="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand pull-left">ComicDB</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
                <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                            <li><a href="issue.html">Issue</a></li>
                    <li><a href="series.html">Series</a></li>
                    <li><a href="writer.html">Writer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="editor.html">Editor</a></li>
                    <li><a href="letterer.html">Letterer</a></li>
                    <li><a href="colourist.html">Colourist</a></li>
                    <li><a href="coverartist.html">Cover Artist</a></li>
                    <li><a href="inker.html">Inker</a></li>
                    <li><a href="penciler.html">Penciler</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tpb.html">Trade Paper Back</a></li>
                    <li><a href="publisher.html">Publisher</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Banner section -->
    <div class="banner">
            <div class="container">
            <form class="searchbox" action="getIssue.php" method="get">
                <input id="search" type="text" size="35" placeholder=" Series" name="seriesName">
                <input id="search" type="text" placeholder=" Volume" name="volumeName">
                <input id="search" type="text" size="5" placeholder=" NR" name="issueNR">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- Include jQuery and bootstrap JS plugins -->
    <script src="includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image: html without echo]

Comment: there isn't even 1 line of php code in the whole file except echo which in turn is useless here. why you are echoing? just use the same html writing native way.

Comment: Can you post the source code that gets created? (CTRL+U in your browser). Maby you forgot to add <?php add the beginning of the file, but that might just be you forgot to post it here.

Comment: Why `echo` so much HTML?

Comment: @itachi there is ofcourse more code but that's queries, connection to the database, ... and I don't think that's relevant?

Comment: You can just code this in plain HTML. No need to echo everything. For example <html><body><more html> <?php your php ?> <html>More html</html>

Comment: The problem is not with php, the problem is with the code you generate with php. Just compare the generated html with your original one.

Comment: @Chilion It's there but there is some database stuff that comes before the echo so I didn't add it

Comment: see source code, see your code.... find the difference. that's where the problem is.

Comment: @TimothyPersoon you don't need all these `echo`, just remove them, write in plain html and whenever you will need to add some PHP then just use `<?php YOUR CODE ?>`.

Comment: Echoing everything makes a non-lineal DOM. Change that for provide a php file with an html-like format but with the tags `<? php // Code here ?>` wherever you need it.

Comment: If there is a difference between what you see in different browsers, it is in most cases css related issue

Comment: So many similar comments. I think this echo thing is contagious!

Comment: well i gues the problem here is that there are no linebreaks like \n, try to use a single echo with multiline - second is that u include bootstrap js and css - there are known issues that this will modify ur code unexpected when not using there grid system - third seems that the border radius is to big so the form gets streched out + height, lower the radius and add a fixed padding to this div

Comment: Please post content from "includes/style.css".

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then because when I remove the echo, I just get a white page. There are a lot of comments so I'm going to try to follow each one

Comment: you sould remove `<?` or `<?php` open (and close `?>`) tag too and all echo-s because this seems to be a static page (so far...), Note: you can get nothing (blank page) too, if there is a php compile/syntax error and no error outputting is enabled. (see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/669677)

Comment: @2astalavista see revised output

Comment: Alright everyone, got it working. Thanks for the (sometimes not so) constructive feedback.

Comment: Timothy Persoon, please post the content from "includes/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

@Timothy Persoon use this css and change colors of this code :)
!same class you used in menu bar "container" and search!

```css
body{ background-color:#FFF;}
.container{
margin-left:20%;
width:520px;
height:20px;
padding:20px;
border: 5px #888888 solid;
background-color: #cbce2c;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```